# Как сделать не завершающий фоновый процесс

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

Имею проблему нужно чтобы служба приложении работала в фоновом режиме и показывала оповещения даже когда пользователь удалил его из перечня запущенных программ. Пользовался такими приложениями знаю, что такое возможно но как. У меня оповещения показывает только когда приложение активно или свернутое.
Что нужно изменить или добавить в коде?

YourService.java

```
public class YourService extends Service {

    private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;
    private static final String NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID = "Channel_Id";


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        startForeground();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    private void startForeground() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
                NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID) 
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Service")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build());
    }
}
```

app.java

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user1.yourservice">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".YourService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Запускаю приложение на xiaomi redmi note 4x Andoird 7.0(API 24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать фоновый процесс,который будет работать даже, когда приложение удалено из перечня запущенных программ можно с помощью Foreground Service. У вас в принципе правильно. Но проблема есть. Она происходит из-за того, что вы тестируете на Xiaomi. Прошивка Xiaomi MIUI убивает Foregound Service, когда вы удаляете приложение из перечня запущенных программ, в отличии от обычного андроида. Вот такая вот **фича** прошивки, которая сделана для того, чтобы экономить заряд батареи. Ее может изменить только сам пользователь телефона в настройках(в интернете есть гайды).

Обычно разработчики никак не обрабатывают эту фичу. Можете скачать какое-нибудь знаменитое приложение, например AIMP, и проверить.

В качестве теста своего кода вы можете протестировать свой код на эмуляторе. Там все будет работать ожидаемо. Не забудьте протестировать и на api > 26. Там у вас будет ошибка, чтобы ее устранить нужно правильно создать канал нотификаций. Например, вот так.

```
 private void startForeground() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    initChannels(getApplicationContext()); //создаем notification channel

    startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
            "default")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Service")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build());
}

public void initChannels(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {
        return;
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
            "Channel name",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("Channel description");
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background вот, что мне нужно но все равно когда закрываю приложение то оповещения исчезает

Comment: мне нужно так сказать "вечно" работающие приложения

Comment: Я изменил ответ под ваш случай